# get cookie of other website on my webpage

Tags: php

I am trying to get the facebook cookie on my webpage, but I am being unabe to do this.
I tried this but it returned null.
Please give me the php script if you know.

Comment: Please show your code, especially that which "returned null".

Answer (score 2):

### You are trying to do the impossible.

You just can't read other websites cookies, you may just could read their headers though.

---

You could grab their headers like this.

```
<?php
file_get_contents('https://www.facebook.com');
var_dump($http_response_header);
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be a huge security issue on both Facebook's end and the browser's end.
You should never be able to do that ever for any reason ever.